# Trying to build Android default email client but missing Calendar provider

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I've downloaded the source code for the Android default email client.  I'd like to build it to try some things out but I am unable to.  It seems I am missing a reference to the Android Calendar provider as both Eclipse and NetBeans complain about this import along with any other references:

```
import android.provider.Calendar;
```

When I browse the sdk it looks like this provider is not included.

So - how can I load the provider so I can build the client?  Is there any other way for me to build the default Android email client locally?  I've started to go down the road of downloading all the Android source code and building from there but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Also, ideally I'd like to build against Android 2.2/Froyo but would consider 2.1 or 2.3 if that made this easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So - how can I load the provider so I can build the client?

That application can only be built as part of the full firmware. It cannot be built as an SDK application.

You may wish to consider the [K9 application](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/) instead. It is a clone of the original email client, substantially rewritten to be an SDK application plus add other features/bug fixes.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the calendar provider even though it is hidden. You can even create your own SDK variant that includes it.

The guide below contains a good description on how to access the built-in calendar provider

http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151